# Sending emails from react app to logged in users via express api/nodemailer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, nodemailer

Goal: I am working on a side project that uses React for frontend and Express.js for backend. My goal is to send acknowledgement emails to logged in users via nodemailer using express api.

Progress:

I have set up HTTPS for my react app that lives in Amazon s3 via Cloudfront and route53. I did this by attaching the domain name(https://www.example.com) to the cloudfront distribution via Route53. I used AWS ACM to create the cert.

My backend code lives in an EC2 instance, I have set up HTTPS for the backend api **api.example.com**. I used certbot to configure lets encrypt cert and pointed nginx server name to api.example.com to configure HTTPS.

I have setup a backend api to notify logged in users. I send emails using nodemailer.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: process.env.USERNAME,
    pass: process.env.PWD
  },
});

exports.emailAck = function (req, res) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'Testing email',
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: "Thank you for submitting the request for :  " + req.body.id,
    text: "TBD",
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        res.json({status: "error", message: error});
    }
    else {
        res.json({ status: "success", message: "Email sent" });
    }
});
};
```

Problem:

1. My emails are being sent only when I turn on allow less secure apps in gmail.. Even though my app is secured, I am not sure why this is happening

[image]

2. When I try to store my transporter auth credentials in .env file to protect the secrets, I see a Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN" error but if I try to add plaintext in the given file below, it works.

I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login in the react side to setup login functionality.

I am wondering if I should restrict my backend api in EC2 to just allow access to the react app so it wouldn't be considered less secure application...

I would appreciate any direction with the above two issues,If there is a better solution other than node mailer, I am open to trying it.

Thanks in advance. I can clarify any questions in the edits if anything is not clear, so please let me know.

Comment: That's some great effort! Apart from the technical point of view. I would suggest you use an email service provider instead of configuring your own email in the server. That's not the purpose of your gmail account. For example, I would register a domain and use "SendGrid" to handle email service. One of the benefits of doing this is, it saves your hassle to config your server (you just need to call send email endpoint of Sendgrid), it reduces the risk that your email is considered as a SPAM (you may never undo this...)...etc etc

Comment: Oh I see, interesting - thanks Nick, for the insights, I will look into SendGrid

Comment: Have your read https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/ and the conclusion at the end? tldr; use a dedicated provider or OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

For issue number 2, if you are using dotenv package for environment variables,you should load the config like this in your js file

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, I still saw the same error